# PHP cURL file upload append infomation to the file

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I upload file to the remote server. The code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ZDURL.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ZDUSER."/token:".ZDAPIKEY);

    $params = array('file_name' => '@'.$temp_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/plain"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

But in the top of uploaded file appears information:

```
------------------------------cfbe90a606af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_name"; filename="C:\Program Files\xampp\tmp\phpF576.tmp"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

images have wrong format owing to this addition text

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain` makes no sense here given that you are talking about images (and in general when passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`). What are you trying to do, mimic a form submission, POST a raw image or what?

Comment: POST a raw image. I use this sample http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the URL you are sending data to is expecting just a file in the request body, rather than a form submission. The best way to achieve this is with `CURLOPT_INFILE`. Try this code:

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ZDURL.$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ZDUSER."/token:".ZDAPIKEY);

// You need to detect the correct content type for the file you are sending.
// Although based on the current problem you have, it looks like the server
// ignores this anyway
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));

// Send the raw file in the body with no other data
$fp = fopen($temp_file, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```